# Using iMac: Libre Office freezing. Series of crashes and reboot problems

Tags: boot, login, libreoffice, mac

When I updated the software today, using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and restarted, it failed to reboot or show a login screen. Instead, I get this message:

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 280773/19505152 files, 7038094/78011392 blocks
```

Then the text disappears and leaves a blinking cursor in the top left of the screen. Nothing happens when I type.

I am using an iMac from 2009. Processor: 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. It is dedicated to Linux, not partitioned.

Looking for solutions, I tried hitting Ctrl + Alt+ F2. This got me through to a login, but it is not recognising the username as I remember it (I am the sole user, and with the normal login screen it shows my name, so I hoped that would be straightforward).

I tried restarting and holding down left shift, or right shift, or Esc, or Tab: the Grub menu does not appear.

I have tried booting with a USB stick which I originally used to install the system.

I have also tried booting with another USB stick onto which I copied Boot Repair Disk.

Am I missing something simple?

---

Update #1:

After following the steps described in my own answer, immediately below, for a couple of days I was able to use the system. However, there were still crashes. I also had difficulty opening some of the files in use at the time of the original crash. The problem seemed to be to do with files opened with Libre Office: a window would ask about recovering files, and then freeze when that process was started.

I put off trying to work out what was going on exactly, until now: this time the crash is one that I can't recover from by restarting, or by powering off/on. Nor can I reboot from the live USB stick which had worked so recently. No access at all to other terminal screens either via Ctrl + Alt + Fn2 etc (no response at all to those keys).

The latest situation is that I am stuck with a screen which reads:

```
[    1.25255] initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Update #2:

Managed to boot to the live USB successfully, after an interval of over a week.

Libre Office continued to cause crashes. Message about `initramfs unpacking failed` returned, so following a search of posts on Ask Ubuntu, I tried:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

`reboot`

Freezing continued with Libre Office.

Checked to see if Autosave was disabled: it already was.

Without knowing much at all, decided to install `linux-crashdump` in an effort to get some information about the crashes. But soon realized I don't know how to use it.

Updated version of Libre Office, from command line.

Freezing with Libre Office continued. Until I returned to the position of the end of Update #1, ie unable to reboot, nor to boot to live USB. Message
`initramfs unpacking failed` returned.

---

Update 3:

Inexplicably, soon afterwards I managed to boot to Live USB and re-install. Then after a couple of soft re-starts, Libre Office allowed me to access and use the problem files (Calc).
While it leaves me feeling resilient, it would be good to know what else I could be doing constructively...

---

Update 4:

Libre Office seemed to trigger crashes again, after an interval of days. Meanwhile, I have learned enough to approach a possible diagnosis, so I hope this question can be useful to others too. Opening the Log application, searches relating to 2 sessions today, between restarts, produced these results (note **libre office** in session B):

Session A

1. hardware log message:

nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0100618034 on channel -1 [0fedf000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]

Kernel device: +pci:0000:03:00.0
priority 3

2. 'other' log message:

sender: gdm-session-wor
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

3. 'other' log message:

sender: fido_id

3-1.3:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory

Session B
searched applications log for 'office'>

1. Applications log messages:
   javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
   Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common
   is installed.
   If it is already installed then try removing ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/javasettings_Linux_*.xml

oosplash
Warning: failed to read path from javaldxame

Following this clue, I tried:

```
whereis java
```

leading to:

```
/usr/share/java
```

then:

```
me@me-iMac:/usr/share/java$ ls -l
total 440
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5386 Aug 24 23:58 java_uno.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55773 Aug 24 23:58 juh-6.4.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Aug 24 23:58 juh.jar -> juh-6.4.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111574 Aug 24 23:58 jurt-6.4.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Aug 24 23:58 jurt.jar -> jurt-6.4.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2602 Mar 22  2020 libintl.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 255440 Aug 24 23:58 ridl-6.4.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Aug 24 23:58 ridl.jar -> ridl-6.4.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4455 Aug 24 23:58 unoloader-6.4.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Aug 24 23:58 unoloader.jar -> unoloader-6.4.6.jar
```

As a novice, at this stage the update to Java is challenging. Any advice?

Update 5:

Went ahead and installed default-jre and default-jdk. Libre Office is working again. Will monitor it.

For the other novices out there, now when I run `whereis java`, the result is much healthier:`java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Rebooted with live USB stick originally used to install Ubuntu.

Because it is a Mac, I pressed the Alt (or Option) key while restarting [this was discovered by a Google search]. This took me through to the iMac's EFI install menu, where I was able to select the correct USB stick.

Erased existing system files and installed Ubuntu afresh.

Noted username.